scrollIntoView is not scrolling to the element
I want to smoothly scroll the page. I have a state to track the user-selected FAQ and a useEffect that triggers when there is a question id change. However, scrollIntoView is not scrolling the page even though I see the element in the console.
I add an element id to the URL, which navigates the page to that element. I also added smooth scroll behavior. However I don't want this; I want to use scrollIntoView.
FaqsMain component:
'use client';
import React from 'react';

import Box from '@/components/ui/Box';
import Faqs from './Faqs';
import FaqGroups from './FaqGroups';
import FaqsSearch from './FaqsSearch';
export default function FaqsMain() {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = React.useState<string>();

  return (
    <section className='bg-gray-100 '>
      <FaqsSearch setSelectedId={setSelectedId} />
      <Box className='max-w-[1300px] mx-auto'>
        <FaqGroups />
        <Faqs selectedId={selectedId} />
      </Box>
    </section>
  );
}

FaqsSearch component:
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import Text from '@/components/ui/Text';
import styles from './styles.module.css';
import { cn } from '@/util/cn';
import { Input } from '@nextui-org/react';
import { IoSearch } from 'react-icons/io5';
import Box from '@/components/ui/Box';
import useDebounce from '@/hooks/useDebounce';
import { faqs as defaultFaqs } from './data';
import Show from '@/components/ui/Show';
import useElementMetrics from '@/hooks/useElementMetrics';
import { useOutSideClick } from '@/hooks/useOutSideClick';

export default function FaqsSearch({
  setSelectedId,
}: {
  setSelectedId: React.Dispatch<
    React.SetStateAction<string | undefined>
  >;
}) {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const ulRef = React.useRef<HTMLUListElement>(null);
  const inputMetrics = useElementMetrics(inputRef);
  const [faqs, setFaqs] = React.useState(defaultFaqs);
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState('');
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = React.useState('');

  useDebounce(
    () => {
      setDebouncedValue(val);
    },
    300,
    [val]
  );
  useOutSideClick({
    ref: ulRef,
    handler: () => {
      setIsVisible(false);
    },
    enabled: isVisible,
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (debouncedValue.length >= 2) {
      setIsVisible(true);
      setFaqs(
        defaultFaqs.filter(
          faq =>
            faq.answer.includes(debouncedValue) ||
            faq.question.includes(debouncedValue)
        )
      );
    } else {
      setIsVisible(false);
    }
  }, [debouncedValue]);

  return (
    <Box className='relative'>
      <Box className={cn(' pt-72 bg-yellow500 ', styles.container)}>
        <Box className='flex items-center md:max-w-[800px] rounded-full mx-auto flex-col  relative'>
          <Box className='w-[1400px] z-[-1] border-2 border-white h-[1400px] absolute rounded-full -top-36 '></Box>
          <Text color='white' size='5xl' noMargin className='mb-14'>
            FAQ
          </Text>
          <Text
            color='white'
            noMargin
            className='mb-12 text-center  text-lg'
          >
            Find answers to common questions about our services,
            policies, and the benefits of joining us, ensuring you
            have all the information you need at your fingertips.
          </Text>
          <Box className='w-[90%] mb-28  mx-auto'>
            <Input
              ref={inputRef}
              value={val}
              onChange={({ currentTarget }) => {
                setVal(currentTarget.value);
              }}
              endContent={<IoSearch size={18} />}
              size='lg'
              placeholder='Search'
              classNames={{
                base: '  block w-full mx-auto',
                inputWrapper: 'bg-white  py-2.5 pl-4 pr-8',
              }}
            />
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <Show when={isVisible}>
        <Box
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: inputMetrics.top,
            left: inputMetrics.left,
            width: inputMetrics.width,
          }}
          className='flex  z-20 w-full justify-center'
        >
          <Box
            ref={ulRef}
            as='ul'
            className='bg-white py-2 w-full h-[200px] overflow-y-auto'
          >
            <Show when={!!faqs.length}>
              {faqs.map((faq, i) => (
                <Text
                  noMargin
                  key={faq.question}
                  as='li'
                  onClick={() => {
                    setSelectedId(faq.id);
                    setIsVisible(false);
                  }}
                  className={cn(
                    'py-1 px-6 border-b cursor-pointer border-b-gray-200',
                    {
                      'border-b-0': i == faqs.length - 1,
                    }
                  )}
                  color='charcoal'
                >
                  {faq.question}
                </Text>
              ))}
            </Show>
            <Show when={!faqs.length}>
              <Text
                noMargin
                as='li'
                className={cn('py-1 px-6')}
                color='charcoal'
              >
                No results found
              </Text>
            </Show>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Show>
    </Box>
  );
}

Faqs component:
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import {
  Accordion,
  AccordionItem,
  Selection,
} from '@nextui-org/react';
import Text from '@/components/ui/Text';
import Box from '@/components/ui/Box';
import { faqs } from './data';
import { usePathname, useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
type AccordionKey = string; // Define a type for the keys

export default function Faqs({
  selectedId,
}: {
  selectedId?: string;
}) {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [selectedKeys, setSelectedKeys] = React.useState<
    Set<AccordionKey>
  >(new Set([faqs.at(0)?.id].filter(Boolean) as AccordionKey[]));

  const handleSelectionChange = (keys: Selection) => {
    if (keys !== 'all') {
      setSelectedKeys(keys as Set<AccordionKey>);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedId) {
      //NOTE - This scrollIntoView is not working as expected however I see the element in the
       console.
      // const ele = document.getElementById(
      //   selectedId
      // ) as HTMLDivElement;
      // NOTE - console.log(ele);
      // ele.scrollIntoView({
      //   behavior: 'smooth',
      //   block: 'end',
      // });
      router.push(`${pathname}#${selectedId}`);
      setSelectedKeys(new Set([selectedId]));
    }
  }, [selectedId, router, pathname]);

  return (
    <Box className='pt-24 pb-44'>
      <Accordion
        selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
        className='gap-14'
        onSelectionChange={handleSelectionChange}
        variant='splitted'
      >
        {faqs.map(faq => (
          <AccordionItem
            id={faq.id}
            classNames={{
              base: '!py-6 !px-24 !shadow-none bg-white',
              indicator: 'text-2xl',
            }}
            key={faq.id}
            aria-label={faq.question}
            title={
              <Text
                color='charcoal'
                className='font-bold'
                size='2xl'
                noMargin
              >
                {faq.question}
              </Text>
            }
          >
            <Text color='charcoal' size='lg' noMargin>
              {faq?.answer}
            </Text>
          </AccordionItem>
        ))}
      </Accordion>
    </Box>
  );
}


try using an element ref to select the element instead of querying the document directly and ensure preventDeafult() is applied to any handler. You don't need to provide an external URL that is not a requirement for asking questions or even recommended and you'd be wise to maintain privacy.

I can't use the ref i think you haven't read my code carefully.

You can put your codes to some online code editor like codesandbox or stackblitz with minimal code, just to see the exact scenario for your problem.
